# Spring JPA Foreign keys are not being created in mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. When I create a table the are no foreign keys being created. Can someone help!

Here are my entities. 
Users

```
Imports......

@Entity
@Table(name = "application_user")
public class ApplicationUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Column(length=40)
private String userName;
@Column(length=100)
private String password;
private int houseNumber;
@Column(length=40)
private String street;
@Column(length=20)
private String city;
@Column(length=20)
private String county;
@Column(length=9)
private String postcode;
@Column(length=60)
private String email;
@Column(length=13)
private String telePhone;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Roles> roles;

Setters and getters.....
```

Roles

```
Imports.......

@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Roles {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Integer id;  
public String name;

Setters and getters.......
```

When I run the application the tables are created, however, there are no foreign keys created.
The SQL that hibernate generates is:

```
drop table if exists application_user;
drop table if exists application_user_roles;
drop table if exists hibernate_sequence;
drop table if exists roles;

create table application_user (
    id integer not null, 
    city varchar(20), 
    county varchar(20), 
    email varchar(60), 
    house_number integer not null, 
    password varchar(100),
    postcode varchar(9), 
    street varchar(40), 
    tele_phone varchar(13), 
    user_name varchar(40), 
    primary key (id)
) ;    

create table application_user_roles (
    application_user_id integer not null, 
    roles_id integer not null
) ;    

create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint); 
insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 );
insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 );

create table roles (
    id integer not null, 
    name varchar(255), 
    primary key (id)
);

alter table application_user_roles add constraint UK_bn9l8a2gm8lytmn3c2cnbxrxm unique (roles_id);
alter table application_user_roles add constraint FK13sbcqjpwynfdukkr8i1xfyj1 
foreign key (roles_id) references roles (id);
alter table application_user_roles add constraint FK9hwva08h4u671cqxpexx1dx7i 
foreign key (application_user_id) references application_user (id)
```

When I look at the tables in MySql Workbench there are no foreign key constraints. But if I run the SQL script in a query window the foreign key constraints are created. Why are the foreign keys not created when hibernate creates the tables? I have tried two MySql servers both with the same outcome.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an entity created for `application_user_roles ` table?

Comment: No I have not got an entity for that. Hibernate auto generated that as the link table.

Comment: What I can't understand is the hibernate generated SQL is correct and should produce the tables in the database correct. It just isnt.